# Response on console is different from preview on network

Tags: http, response, angular7

When I give console.log (response) this appears:

[image]

But when I access the request in the preview of the network, the response is like this:

[image]

Model:

```
export class UserId {
  id: number
  user: string
  name: string 
  email: string
  photo: string
  last_login: string
  password: string
  status: number
  is_admin: number
  dt_created: string
}
```

Service:

```
getUserById(id: number) {
        return this.service.getUserById(`${this.endpointGetUserId}/${id}`)
        .map((response) => {
            return response.user;
        });
    }
```

Http:

```
getUserById(path: string) {
        return this.http.get<UserId>(this.baseUrl  + path);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are checking the same url?